# Matrix Differentation w.r.t. a Vector

Tags: matrix-calculus

Given $\alpha$ a scalar, $\mathbf{X}$ an $N_x \times 1$ vector that is a function of $\alpha$, $\mathbf{U}$ an $N_u \times 1$ vector that is a function of $\alpha$ and $\mathbf{X}$, and $\mathbf{C}$ an $N_u \times N_u$ matrix that is a function of $\alpha$, $\mathbf{X}$, and $\mathbf{U}$. I am trying to compute the total derivative of $\mathbb{F} = \mathbf{C} \mathbf{U}$ with respect to $\alpha$ using the chain rule:

$$\underbrace{\frac{d \mathbb{F}}{d \alpha}}_{N_u \times 1} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbb{F}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_u \times 1} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbb{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}}_{N_u \times N_x} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_x \times 1} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbb{F}}{\partial \mathbf{U}}}_{N_u \times N_u} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{U}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_u \times 1},$$

The first term is straight forward. How can I compute the second term on the RHS and put it in the above form (i.e., put $\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}$ on the right)?

I figured out the following:

$$\underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbb{F}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}}_{N_u \times N_x} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_x \times 1} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{C}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}}_{N_u \times N_u \times N_x} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_x \times 1} \underbrace{\mathbf{U}}_{N_u \times 1} + \underbrace{\mathbf{C}}_{N_u \times N_u} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{U}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}}_{N_u \times N_x} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}}_{N_x \times 1},$$

As you can see, confusion comes from the first term on the RHS in the above equation. I can't figure out how to perform the derivative of the matrix $\mathbf{C}$ with respect to $\mathbf{X}$ and how to put the size correctly so the multiplication is correct. Finally, in such case, is it possible to reorder the term to put $\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha}$ on the right?

The context is optimization of fluid-structure interaction problems if any one is interested. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The gradient $\,\Gamma=\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right)$ is a third-order tensor which cannot be written using standard matrix notation, however, in index notation it's quite simple. Or, depending on the specific functions used to define $(x,u,C),\,$ it may be possible to obtain the desired gradient without requiring any third-order tensors.

Comment: 1. $C$ is one of the finite element matrices used to model Navier-Stokes equations. I have many of these matrices so I wrote it general to get help with the basic idea. 2. I think now it might be simpler to simply differentiate with a single element of $X$ each time and rearrange the final result (e.g. for loop in code, not the most efficient). I was just hoping to write a compact expression for this equation. 3. Would you kindly show me an example on how to do this in index notation? Or direct me to a nice resource on matrix calculus (applied more than abstract would be much better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Let's
use a convention where an uppercase Latin letter represents a matrix, lowercase Latin a vector, and lowercase Greek a scalar, i.e. make the following substitutions
$$F\to f\quad U\to u\quad X\to x$$
Let's also avoid subscripted variable names, because we'll be using subscripts to denote components and summations
$$N_u\to n\qquad N_x\to m$$
Now we're ready to convert the expressions
$$\eqalign{
f &= Cu \\
\p{f}{x}\,\p{x}{\alpha}
 &= \p{C}{x}\,\p{x}{\alpha}\,u + C\,\p{u}{x}\,\p{x}{\alpha} \\
}$$
to index notation
$$\eqalign{
f_i &= \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}u_j \\
\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\p{f_i}{x_k}\,\p{x_k}{\alpha}\right)
 &= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m\left(
  \p{C_{ij}}{x_k}\,\p{x_k}{\alpha}\,u_j + C_{ij}\,\p{u_j}{x_k}\,\p{x_k}{\alpha}
 \right) \\\\
}$$
So that's the brute-force method, but if you tell us the functions which define the $(C,u,x)$ variables, then there may be an easier solution to the problem.

Comment: I think I got the gist of it, thank you.